# git branch master origin/master のブランチを作成した後の動作が分からない

Tags: git

cloneしたのがdevelopブランチだったので、今日業務で下記のコマンドを実行してリモートブランチのmasterをローカルのブランチに落とす作業を行いました。

これってローカルにmasterブランチを作成して、そこにリモートブランチをマージしているという流れになっているのでしょうか。

gitの操作にまだ慣れていなくて、詳しい方教えて下さると幸いです。
宜しくお願い致します。

```bsh
リモートブランチを同期させる。
git fetch
# fetchしたリモートブランチを確認する
git branch -r
git checkout -b master origin/master
```

#### 追記

checkoutはブランチを切り替えるだけなので、個人的に気になるのは下記の内容だと思います。
これって内部的にはdevelopブランチからmasterを切ってそこにリモートリポジトリのmasterをpullしていてpullはfetch+mergeと聞いたのでmergeが動作していると考えているのですが、いかがでしょうか。

```
git branch master origin/master
```

状況はdevelopブランチにいた状態で `git checkout -b master origin/master` からmasterという名前のブランチを切って、そこにpullしてるイメージなのですが　`git log`　を見る限りローカルのmasterブランチにリモートのmasterがマージされた形跡はなかったです。

これと同じ意味だと思うんですけど、これを実行すると指定したコミットログ以下のコミットがあるブランチが作成される。
ここを `origin/master` にするとリモートリポジトリのmaster最新コミットログを起点にブランチが作成される。
これはおそらくdevelopとは完全に独立したブランチになる。
二本柱ができるようなイメージになるんですかねおそらく。

```
// 起点を指定して、ブランチ作成
git branch <branch> <commit>
```

#### 参照

下記の記事を見ると上記はマージしてるような事が書いてある
https://shu223.hatenablog.com/entry/20130115/1367342778

質問とは少し関係ないけど、 `git checkout -b master origin/master` で派生する親のブランチを間違えそのまま開発した際の対処法
https://www.granfairs.com/blog/staff/git-mistake-parent-branch

Comment: 「cloneしたのがdevelopブランチだったので」は、具体的にどのようなコマンドで clone したか覚えていますか？ / "動作が分からない" と聞くよりも、なにか目標となる状態があって、それを達成するには何を行えばよいか？みたいな質問にした方が具体的な回答をしやすいかもしれません。

Comment: git clone developブランチのURLでcloneしました。

Comment: 目標となる状態よりもその仕組みが気になります。目標で言えばリモートのブランチを引っ張って来れてるので達成出来ています。

Answer (score 1):

`git checkout` はブランチを切り替えるコマンドであり、マージを行うなら `git merge` を実行する必要があります。

あなたが実行した `git checkout -b master origin/master` は、リモートブランチ "origin/master" を元にローカルブランチ "master" に切り替えるが、`-b` を付けているのでローカルブランチが存在しなければその場で作成する…になります。

なお、ブランチの切り替えは `git checkout` の代わりに現在は `git siwtch` が推奨されます。

---

#### 余談

今回の Git に限らず、コマンド等で分からない事があればまずマニュアルを参照することをおすすめします。Git ならコマンドで `git help` を使うことで man マニュアルと同じように使い方を調べられます。

例: checkout についてなら `git help checkout`

Comment: その場でブランチを作成した後の動作が気になります。
git helpですね。ありがとうございます。